# PHP problems with DateTime modified comparison

Tags: php, date, datetime

This is a problem I'm facing on a PHP script called by a cron every half an hour:

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->modify("+2 hours");   

if ($dt > new DateTime("01:00:00") && $dt < new DateTime("2:00:00")) {      
    include_once("../p-auto.php");
    $fipw = fopen('../logs/cron_f.txt', 'a');
    fwrite($fipw, "p-auto cron: ".date("F j, Y, g:i a").PHP_EOL);
    fclose($fipw);
}else{
    $fipw = fopen('../logs/cron_f.txt', 'a');
    fwrite($fipw, "NOT p-auto: ".date("F j, Y, g:i a").PHP_EOL);
    fclose($fipw);

}
```

the log I saw on the server is like this:

```
NOT p-auto: April 20, 2020, 11:07 pm
NOT p-auto: April 20, 2020, 11:39 pm
NOT p-auto: April 21, 2020, 12:07 am
NOT p-auto: April 21, 2020, 12:36 am
NOT p-auto: April 21, 2020, 1:06 am
NOT p-auto: April 21, 2020, 1:36 am
NOT p-auto: April 21, 2020, 2:08 am
NOT p-auto: April 21, 2020, 2:36 am
NOT p-auto: April 21, 2020, 3:06 am
NOT p-auto: April 21, 2020, 3:36 am
NOT p-auto: April 21, 2020, 4:08 am
```

The problem seems to be started once I added the `$dt-modify`, what I suspect is that since I'm modifying a dateTime between the date change, this leads to some kind of error on the if test.

Now, I cannot modify the settings of the server (it's not owned by me and I cannot ask any kind of customization) and the timezone of the server is configured to be 2 hours behind the real local time.
I can only modify my PHP scripts, so I'm a bit limited in what I can achieve.

Please if someone as some kind of suggestion, I'm struck on this problem since a week...

Comment: I don't see a date change in your log.

Comment: sorry, wrong log, updated it:D

Comment: You don’t need access to the central server / PHP configuration to change the timezone your own PHP script uses … https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: @CBroe nice point, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, I cannot modify the settings of the server (it's not owned by me and I cannot ask any kind of customization) and the timezone of the server is configured to be 2 hours behind the real local time. I can only modify my PHP scripts

That’s all you need, specifying the time zone you want your own script instance to operate with, can be done at run-time using [`date_default_timezone_set()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Any problems with crossing the date boundary, that were caused by the initially attempted workaround of adding two hours to the datetime instance manually, should then not present themself any more to begin with.